# Apply and validate a bound DataGridViewComboBoxCell directly upon selection change

Tags: winforms, validation, datagridview, combobox

I have a windows forms `DataGridView` that contains some `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`s that are bound to a source collection using `DataSource`, `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties. Currently the the combobox cell commits the changes (i.e. `DataGridView.CellValueChanged` is raised) only after I click on another cell and the combobox cell loses focus.

How would I ideally commit the change directly after a new value was selected in the combobox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is written into the implementation of the `DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl`. Thankfully, it can be overridden. First, you must create a subclass of the aforementioned editing control, overriding the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` method:

```
protected override void OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnSelectedIndexChanged(e);

    EditingControlValueChanged = true;
    EditingControlDataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
    EditingControlDataGridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
}
```

This will ensure that the `DataGridView` is properly notified of the change in item selection in the combo box when it takes place.

You then need to subclass `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` and override the `EditType` property to return the editing control subclass from above (e.g. `return typeof(MyEditingControl);`). This will ensure that the correct editing control is created when the cell goes into edit mode.

Finally, you can set the `CellTemplate` property of your `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to an instance of the cell subclass (e.g. `myDataGridViewColumn.CellTemplate = new MyCell();`). This will ensure that the correct type of cell is used for each row in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using [Bradley's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4029933/4794), but it was sensitive to when you attached the cell template. It seemed like I couldn't allow the design view to wire up the column, I had to do it myself.

Instead, I used the binding source's PositionChanged event, and triggered updates from that. It's a little bit odd, because the control is still in edit mode, and the databound object doesn't get the selected value yet. I just updated the bound object myself.

```
    private void bindingSource_PositionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (MyBoundType)bindingSource.Current.MyBoundProperty = 
            ((MyChoiceType)comboBindingSource.Current).MyChoiceProperty;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to achieve this that I am using successfully rather than subclassing or the somewhat inelegant binding source method above, is the following (sorry it's VB but if you can't translate from VB to C# you have bigger problems :)

```
Private _currentCombo As ComboBox

Private Sub grdMain_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles grdMain.EditingControlShowing
    If TypeOf e.Control Is ComboBox Then
        _currentCombo = CType(e.Control, ComboBox)
        AddHandler _currentCombo.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf SelectionChangedHandler
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub grdMain_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles grdMain.CellEndEdit
    If Not _currentCombo Is Nothing Then
        RemoveHandler _currentCombo.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf SelectionChangedHandler
        _currentCombo = Nothing
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SelectionChangedHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim myCombo As ComboBox = CType(sender, ComboBox)
    Dim newInd As Integer = myCombo.SelectedIndex

    //do whatever you want with the new value

    grdMain.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(True)
    grdMain.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
End Sub
```

That's it.